# Screen to log output data from windows service

Tags: windows, service, output

We are looking for some kind of screen that allow us to display some plain text. This text is the output from a windows service. The service is a gateway with a monitoring central that listen some life risk events.

We can't display these events in the server display, because this server is not loged In. We also need that if the server is restarted or anything, data remain visible on the screen regardless.

Anybody knows a device like this?

We are using some Epson LX-300 to do this work right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fast, cheap, n dirty, SysInternals Debug View (dbgview) will permit monitoring other computers; any output via OutputDebugString() will be displayed on the computer that's running dbgview.  This, of course, assumes that you have that much control over how the output is emitted, which you didn't specify.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The solution should work when anything fails (network, internet, service listener...). We have a console application that we can manage remotly, but when we have an electric problem or something like this, only the servers have UPS power.